# ZF2 segment route with file extension

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a route to an action which returns a pdf file. Now it would be fine if the url would contain the file extension `.pdf`. If the last part of my route is not a segment, it should work but not in my case.

**Works**

```
'my_route' => [
    'type' => 'segment',
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/my-file.pdf',
        'defaults' => [
            'action' => 'file'
        ]
    ]
],
```

**Does not work**

```
'my_route' => [
    'type' => 'segment',
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/my-file/:year.pdf',
        'constraints' => [
            'year' => '\d{4}'
        ],
        'defaults' => [
            'action' => 'file',
            'year' => date('Y')
        ]
    ]
],
```

Comment: You may need to use a regex route for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using Regex route (not fully tested):

```
'my_route' => [
    'type' => 'regex',
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/my-file/(?<year>\d{4}).pdf?',
        'constraints' => [
        'defaults' => [
            'action' => 'file',
            'year' => date('Y')
        ]
    ]
],
```

See the docs : https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-regex

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust it to this:

```
'route' => '/my-file/:year:.pdf',
```

Note the extra `:` after the parameter